# Unable to upload file from selenium as upload is not input attribute

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

My issues is that, I am unable to upload file to the below html-

```html
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root jss109 MuiButton-text" tabindex="0" type="button" xpath="1"><span class="MuiButton-label" style="">Click here to browse</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
```

```html
public void uploadSampleMultipleMediaFile() {
        try {
            browseMMSFile.sendKeys("MMS-Files/xxx.txt");
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException e) {
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            // Setting value for "style" attribute to make textbox visible
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display='block';", browseMMSFile);
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root jss109 MuiButton-text']"))
                    .sendKeys("MMS-Files//xxx.txt");
        }
    }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You are looking exclusively at the button DOM, but check if there is any box beside the button;. Usually that box would have the `type=file` attribute. If so, you make use of that locator and use send keys to upload. Otherwise, you may have to make use of autoIT or Robot class of Java

Comment: autoIT or Robot class will it work on selenium grid also ?